# In bootstrap css, I want to use form elements the resize nicely with the grid layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem here.  If I leave the `form-control` class applied, I can see the password chars when I type (it sets the font foreground and background) but it also sets the width to 100% which makes the input control too wide.  If it remove the `form-control` class then I can't see the input and I lose the nice padding effects in the text.  Is there a clean way to fix this?

The old work-around was to add style="width:100px" to the input.  That breaks small screens though.  I really need the grid to work instead.

```
            <div>
                <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input 
                        name="sp" type="password" 
                        class="form-control" 
                        required ng-minlength="9" ng-maxlength="255" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
            </div>
```

ref: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#code

This is a good guide, but it seems all the examples are using fully expanded input elements where there is another visible input element on either side.  I'm using empty elements in the grid to take up space (to center) the input.  http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-forms.php

Comment: "I'm using empty elements in the grid to take up space" Don't do that. Use offset classes instead. See https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/W009 Also, your example is missing a `<div class="row">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example why don't you apply a `max-width` css rule to your input field.

```
@media (min-width: 786px) {
    input[name="sp"] {
        min-width: 100px;
    }
}
```

If you wrap this rule in a media query you'll be able to control the size on small, medium and large layouts while making sure it still looks nice on mobile.

Also rather than using empty `<div class="col-sm-4"></div>` for spacing you can do

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4"></div>
```

Comment: I tried with max-width (it needs to be smaller).. the css inspector is still showing me that (with form-control) the real width is far greater than it needs to be.  That causes it to left justify.

Comment: This is the way to do it.  I suggest adding `display: inline` to your answer.  Bootstrap had it on display:block which was the cause of the expanding effect leading to the left-justification (instead of center).